# Can I host wordpress on Google site?

Tags: wordpress, google-workspace, google-sites

I made a wordpress for client and I want to shifted it to their hosting. He told me that his existing website is on google site as he has a paid Gsuite and if it possible to host thw wordpress website there.
Is that possible? I found some information that I can host it through google cloud but I am not sure if this is right.

Comment: you cannot run a WordPress website on "Google Sites". Also please read [WP Requirements](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/about/requirements/)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible to host Wordpress on Google Sites.
Google Cloud is a completely different service and yes, you can fire up a cloud instance and host anything you want, including Wordpress, but GSuite services do not include this and it will cost additional money for your client.